# Is the Celestial known as "the One Above All" the same being as the One Above All & the One Below All in the "Immortal Hulk" series?

Tags: marvel, comics

Is the Celestial known as One Above All the same being who is both the One Above All & the One Below All featured in the *Immortal Hulk* Marvel Comics series, as well as in other various Marvel comics?

Comment: I know that  the One Above All & the One Below All,from Immortal Hulk & elsewhere,are the same being. The Celestial of the same name has me confused

Answer (score 2):

The Living Tribunal's entry in *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #6](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_6)* clarifies that the [One-Above-All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All_(Multiverse)) who is apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the multiverse is **not** the same being as the [One Above All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All_(Celestial)_(Earth-616)) who is the leader of the Fourth Host of the Celestials.

> HISTORY: The Living Tribunal is a vastly powerful conceptual being, one who has existed since the multiverse came into being. **The Living Tribunal's only superior is the One-Above-All (not to be confused with the Celestial known as the One Above All), the entity which is apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the multiverse, and possibly beyond.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #6* (February, 2009)</sub>